# How to show an img in datatables while i using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

Im working in laravel 5.5 and i implement the datatables and im using it with ajax,i was working fine but now i need to show and img in the datatables but a dont know how. I read the render doc but i still lost.
Table code:

```
<div class="row-fluid margin-body">
                <table id="productos" class="table table-hover table-condensed" >
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th >Id</th>
                                        <th>Producto</th>
                                        <th>Cantidad </th>
                                        <th>img</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>
        </div>
```

Ajax to create the content in table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                listar();
        });
        var listar = function (){
                var table = $('#productos').DataTable({
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax": "ajaxProducto",
                        "columns":[
                                {data:'id'},
                                {data:'nombre'},
                                {data:'stock'},
                                {data: 'imagen',
                                  "render": function(data, type, row) {
                                    return '<img src="'+data+'" />';
                                }},
                                {defaultContent:
                                        "<a type='button' class='editar btn btn-xs btn-mini btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalEditar'>Editar</a><a type='button'  class='eliminar btn btn-xs btn-mini btn-danger' >Eliminar</a><a type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-mini btn-success detalles' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalDetalles'>Detalles</a>"
                                }
                        ],
                        "language": idioma_esp

                });


}
```

This is where i want to show my img

```
    {data: 'imagen',
           "render": function(data, type, row) {
  return '<img src="img/productos/'+data+'" height="42" width="42"/>';    }}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/ajaxProducto', function() {

    return datatables()->collection(App\Producto::all())->toJson();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I find my error while i was writing the question. this code should work for you.

Comment: If you found the error and the question still has value, you should post an explanation of the solution here, in the answer section. If the question no longer has value, you should remove it.